# quantity of R32 in a 5000 BTU window A/C unit

Tags: hvac

What is the best estimate of R32 in a typical 5000 BTU window ac unit? I need to calculate the volume released to atmosphere in the event of a leak.

Comment: It should be in the specs for the AC unit.  Why do you need to calculate it anyway, that is the manufacturers responsibility?

Comment: This question feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve? What is the actual problem?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica  Sounds more like a homework problem.

Answer (score 2):

The amount leaked depends on the particular unit and it is not a predefined amount for a given BTU unit. The charge size can be obtained from the service manual or possibly the manufacturer. R32 refrigerant has a much lower global warming potential (GWP) then R410A which was the popular refrigerant in new air conditioning systems just a few years back.  Worldwide, small air conditioning systems, like window units, are rapidly changing there refrigerant from R410A to R32. Currently R32 exceeds 70% of the market, looking back a few years to 2013 it was effectively zero. This was a huge change in only about 10 years. Slowly it is being introduced to and used in larger and larger systems.

To the best of my knowledge it is required to be reclaimed from units that are being taken out of service but this is a country dependent thing.